# Groups generated by abelian Chernikov's subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Suposse that $G$ is generated by abelian Chernikov's subgroups $H_\lambda$, where $\lambda \in I$ ($I$ is a set of index, not necessary finite), such that $[H_\lambda, H_\beta]=1; \ \lambda, \beta \in I$. Then is $G$ a Chernikov group?

I would also like to know if the direct product of Chernikov Groups is a Chernikov Group. (Any good reference for research would greatly help).

Tanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Chernikov groups, but the definition is that $G$ is Cernikov if it has a normal subgroup of finite index that is a direct product of finitely many quasicyclic groups. So the direct product of infinitely many quasicyclic groups is presumably not Cernikov, so the answer to the first question would appear to be no.

On the other hand, the direct prodcut of two Cernikov groups clearly is a Cernikov group.